# Display FlastList over a ScrollView

Tags: react-native

**Overview**

I want to display a list of text in a vertical scrolling FlatList. Each item in this FlatList can have a changeable background image, and they should stay in sync for each FlatList item. I put the background in a horizontal ScrollView.

**Method 1 - ideal solution**

Here is a mockup of what my ideal solution would be, 1 FlatList and 1 ScrollView. The FlastList has absolute position and is displayed over the ScrollView.
[image: Mockup]

I have built that design out [here in an Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@jaaywags/nexttoeachother). The problem is that the ScrollView stops working.

**Method 2**

I have also attempted to put the FlatList inside the ScrollView. Then each image has it's own FlatList. The problem with that is then you have multiple FlastLists, and then you have to try and keep them in sync as the user scrolls left/right.

**Method 3**

I then tried to work off of that and just have one instance of the FlatList component displayed multiple times. This has the same problem though. They don't stay in sync. You can see an example of that [here in an Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@jaaywags/oneinstanceofcomponent).

I can get method 2 and 3 to work by saving the index of the displayed text, and auto scrolling them to the right offset. I actually built that out locally, but the problem is there can be a delay. And if you are scrolling quick, you see it try to catch up. My FlatList can have 100's of items, so I think the delay comes from trying to sync 100's of FlatLists. I also am hesitant to go this route because I really don't want nested duplicated FlatLists. I feel like that could become a big performance issue very quickly.

I have been trying to solve this for a while, testing out different styling, positions, and methods. No luck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PhantomSpooks - Thank you for your guidance. You gave me an idea on using gestures and so I spent the last two days building this out.

Here is a working [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@jaaywags/finalworkingsolution) example of exactly what I wanted. Doesn't require any external packages either, though, I might publish it as one in the future. Also, that example, the vertical scrolling for the FlatList was not working for the Web tab if you try to click and drag, but using the mouse wheel works. I think that is normal though.

The only issue I see right now is if you swipe left/right quickly, the background image gain an offset. I don't have time to investigate that right now. I could not duplicate this in my React Native non-expo project on an Android Emulator. Probably just because it is a bit laggy and lets the UI catch up.

Comment: omg its beautiful

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you have a list of items. Up and down scrolling is how you cycle through these items, and left and right swipes will change the background for each of these items. If this is the case, then you only need a FlatList for vertical scrolling, and some fling gesture detectors for left and right swipes.

It could look like this:

```js
import React, {useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import { 
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  // if you intend to support both potrait and landscape modes
  // useWindowDimensions will be more useful than Dimensions
  useWindowDimensions,
  ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import {
  GestureDetector,
  Gesture,
  GestureHandlerRootView,
  Directions
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
const backgroundIMages = [
  'https://parispeaceforum.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/NET-ZERO-SPACE-INITIATIVE-1.png',
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/7311920/pexels-photo-7311920.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-alberlan-barros-7311920.jpg&fm=jpg',
  'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YGJ77qN9KiwctZgfqV8Bf3hNo0rZvcFaPKDTkvtS6kVbtwyCS80Pm6dpXzJCCLZE1Q'];
const data = [{
    text: 'test 1',
    imageIndex:0
  },{
    text: 'test 2',
    imageIndex:0
  },{
    text: 'test 3',
    imageIndex:0
  }];
  
export default function App() {
  // because the data has a background that can change
  // it needs to become a state variable
  const [itemData, setItemData] = useState(data);
  // keep track of what item is on screen so only that
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const currentItem = itemData[currentIndex];
 
  
  // wrapped in useCallback to avoid the "onViewableItemsChanged 
  // cannot change on the fly" error
  // when new item comes on screen change currentIndex
  const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(({viewableItems})=>{
    // viewabilityConfig filters what items of the list appears here
    // currently the item has to be 80% on screen, so only one item will
    // be viewable at a time
    let itemOnScreen = viewableItems[0]
    if(!itemOnScreen)
      return
    setCurrentIndex(itemOnScreen.index)
  },[])
  // onRight swipes decrement background for currentItem in view
  const flingRight = Gesture.Fling().direction(Directions.RIGHT).onStart(()=>{
    let newIndex = currentItem.imageIndex -1;
    if(newIndex < 0)
      newIndex = backgroundIMages.length -1
    const newItems = [...itemData];
    currentItem.imageIndex = newIndex
    newItems[currentIndex] = currentItem
    setItemData(newItems)
  })
  // onLeft swipe incremet background for currentItem in view
  const flingLeft = Gesture.Fling().direction(Directions.LEFT).onStart(()=>{
    let newIndex = currentItem.imageIndex +1;
    if(newIndex >= backgroundIMages.length)
      newIndex = 0
    const newItems = [...itemData];
    currentItem.imageIndex = newIndex
    newItems[currentIndex] = currentItem
    setItemData(newItems)
  })
  const fling = Gesture.Exclusive(flingLeft,flingRight)
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.imgBackground}
        source={{uri:backgroundIMages[currentItem.imageIndex]}}
        resizeMode="cover"
      >
        <GestureDetector gesture={fling}>
          <FlatList
            style={[styles.flatList]}
            data={itemData}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View style={styles.flatListView}>
                <Text style={{color: 'red', fontSize: 20}}>{item.text}</Text>
              </View>
            )}
            viewabilityConfig={{
              itemVisiblePercentThreshold:80
            }}
            onViewableItemsChanged={ onViewableItemsChanged }
            extraData={itemData}
          />
        </GestureDetector>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  imgBackground: {
    flex:1
  },
  flatList: {
    flex:1
  },
  flatListView: {
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Try it [here](https://snack.expo.dev/AusSd6XpAq)

Comment: I was testing it on Android but I guess the fling gesture doesnt work for the web

Comment: Might be worth checkout out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72372168/3543339). I have a working example, though the expo snack only partially works on web.